# Text file parser work incorrectly java

Tags: java, parsing

I have text file parser.
And with record like

> 1111 SMITH ROBERT J 1900

work correctly and result is

```
ID: 1111 
LAST NAME: SMITH 
FIRST NAME: ROBERT
MIDDLE NAME: J
MONEY: 1900
```

But if middle name is empty then result is

```
ID: 1111 
LAST NAME: SMITH 
FIRST NAME: ROBERT
MIDDLE NAME: 1900
MONEY: 1900
```

Code:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(token);
Client client = new Client();
while(st.hasMoreElements()){
    String token2 = st.nextElement().toString();
    String[] array = new String[5];
    int i = 0;
    array[i++] = new String(token2);

    String id = array[0];
    String lastName = array[1];
    String firstName = array[2];
    String middleName = array[3];
    String money = array[4];
    client.add(id);
    client.add(lastName);
    client.add(firstName);
    client.add(middleName);
    client.add(money);
}
listResult.add(client);
```

How i can fix it?

Comment: Post real code please. You will cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on `String money = array[4]` because you create it with only 4 element.

Answer (score 1):

If money has a specific format (like in our case, where it seems to be a number), then you can backtrack:

- you read N values per line
- if N = 5, then you're done
- if N = 4, you can check if array[3] is a number, in that case you shift values (eg: array[4] = array[3], array[3] = "") otherwise array[4] = 0 ("no money").
- for other values of N, you have to decide what to do.

By the way, your code smells bad:

```
String token2 = st.nextElement().toString();
String[] array = new String[4];
int i = 0;
array[i++] = new String(token2);
```

1. `token2` is already a `String`, there is no need to call `new String(token2)`.
2. `int i = 0; array[i++]` => will always write the same value.
3. You can reuse the array (eg: put the line 2 before the loop) using `Arrays.fill(array, null)` thus avoiding new object allocation.
4. You should call your method `setFirstName`, `setLastName`, etc on your Client class, and not do something that looks like a `List` but is not a `List`.